# How do I read a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am having some problems reading from a file. I have two header files: a and b. b is derived from a,and c is derived from b. Now i want to open a text file.

The whole format is like this:

> A john
>
> A johnee
>
> P 123

If the first charcter is 'a' and 'p' is also there, then print the second line, else print the first line.

```
#include "c.h"
#include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
using namespace std;
c :: c()
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open ("abc.txt");
    ch = input.get();
    input >> ch;
    if (ch ='A')
        a* z =new a();
    else 
    input.close();
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I fixed most of your question, please try a little harder to be understandable in the future, it will help people to answer your questions.

Comment: I still can't make heads or tails out of what he's asking for.

Comment: *Onorio: I know, but it is the best I can do. You should have seen it before...

Comment: perhaps we should ask his teacher for the exam question in the first place?

Comment: I hate to sound obnoxious, but this sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: retagged, also I hate the tag visualc++, I'm not sure what this refers to other than maybe c++ in visual studio.

Comment: What is the policy on doing homework?

Comment: @RichB--Wow, I would have hated to see the question _before_ you cleaned it up. :-)

Comment: I'm really tempted to downvote this question just because it's phrased so poorly.  But maybe English is a second language for charu and he (or she) is actually asking a programming question (in contrast to asking for the hidden features of Snobol) so I'll forgo downvoting in this case.

Answer (score 5):

> > If the first charcter is 'a' and 'p' is also there, then print the second line, else print the first line.

Could you give an example of what this program's output should look like based on the text file you have?

I did notice one thing, though:

```
if (ch ='A')
```

Change that to:

```
if (ch =='A')
```

You need to use two =s for comparisons.